# Cannot delete object pointed by stack.top() in template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have template class used for state machine, which is partial declared for the pointer type objects. In this class there is attribute:

```
std::stack<T*> s;
```

and there is a method used to pop top state:

```
void SM<T*>::pop()
{
    delete s.top();
    s.pop();
}
```

There is no error during compilation process, but when this method is called, my program stops. Any idea why?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer your question. Please provide a [MCVE]. My only guess based on this code would be that maybe `s` is already empty.

Comment: don't you have to check whether stack has any elements before s.top () ?

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: stack isn't empty, when I comment delete everything works fine, but as far as I know, there is a memory leak here

Comment: stack was empty?  Element wasn't allocated with new?  Program exited main normally?  Something else?  We are programmers, not psychics.  You need to be clear on precisely what is wrong (expected vs observed), and give a complete enough program that we can run it and see the same results.

Comment: a memory leak won't "stop" your program.  Invalid use of memory may, however.

Comment: I doubt you need pointers at all, but if you do: `std::stack<std::unique_ptr<T>> s;` should make this easier. Just move it out, use it if you want to and let it be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Okay, I tried to reproduce this problem in simple program, but then everything is working. I came to the conclusion that the problem is probably that I'm calling `pop()` method from object I want to destroy but I have to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why?

Most likely reason is that `s.top()` doesn't point to an object whose lifetime hasn't ended, and which was created using non-array allocating `new` .

To avoid this problem, it is a good idea to avoid owning bare pointers.